# Embedding lua in my C# application : require "luainterface" fails

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I downloaded the newest version of LuaInterface from their site, and referenced LuaInterface.dll and Lua51.dll. The interpreter itself works fine, but when I try to require("luainterface"), I get this exception :

```
error loading module 'luainterface' from file '.\luainterface.dll':
The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Here's the example code which produces this behavior :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Lua lua = new Lua();
        lua.DoFile("test.lua");
    }
```

The test.lua script just has this :

```
luanet = require("luainterface");
```

Also, I've made sure that LUA_PATH points to where luanet.dll is.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For .dll's are looked for in LUA_CPATH in any case...
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath

Comment: Did you mean ".DLL" instead of ".DDL"?